BindingListView library allows for adding new items which would show on DataGridView?
I am using the BindingListView library from waynebloss on github. I have used the example:
List<Customer> customers = GetCustomers();
BindingListView<Customer> view = new BindingListView<Customer>(customers);
dataGridView1.DataSource = view;


To create a BindingListView source and add it as DataSource on DataGridView. Then, I have added an item to the List later on using Add() function. In the example above it would be customers.Add(customer). Though, the items added do not show on the DataGridView. Does the library support what I want to do? I originally used BindingList but it does not support filtering.

I have used the Refresh() method of BindingListView on each addition and that actually results in showing the items. Though, does not that defeat the purpose of a BindingListView? I also created BindingList instead of a List and used it with BindingListView and that eliminated the need for Refresh() Though, I am not sure if this is the proper solution or not.

The use of a BindingList is correct here, since this class propagates changes related to its content. The custom collection you're using probably doesn't, or relies in an external implementation (quite common in Winforms, unless you also manually implement INotifyPropertyChanged / INotifyCollectionChanged in your class / models) -- I don't see how Refresh() would change anything, since that forces a repaint of the graphic interface, it doesn't affect the binding

@Jimi I am sorry but I did not fully understand what you are saying. Are you saying I should use BindingList (instead of List) with BindingListView? As for Refresh() it actually caused the DataGridView to refresh with the items added to the ``List`.

Well, my comment is quite explicit. Anyway, YES, a BindingList is the correct tool, since, as mentioned, propagates collection change events in a way that Winforms tools understand. Your base class(es) should also implement INotifyPropertyChanged, the BindingList doesn't do that (a DataTable, for example, does) -- There's no possible way that a call to Refresh() affects the data, since it's completely unrelated

BTW, I don't know that library, but, if it follows standard specifications, it may be possible that adding / removing elements to / from the BindingListView instead of the original collection, may generate an event that notifies the new insertion in a way that bound Controls can understand

Using a strongly typed datatable would probably solve your problem too
